# How is a linear autoencoder equal to PCA?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, pca, autoencoder

I would like the mathematical proof of it. does anyone know a paper for it. or can workout the math?

Comment: See [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/120080/whatre-the-differences-between-pca-and-autoencoder) or [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/204552/why-would-i-ever-use-a-linear-autoencoder-for-dimensionality-reduction?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: thanks but I wanted the mathematical proof

Comment: It's hard to do that here because SO does not have Latex and it's a little off-topic; I'd post on the math stack exchange or the stats stack exchange instead. :)

Comment: Also, look [here](https://pvirie.wordpress.com/2016/03/29/linear-autoencoders-do-pca/) and [here](http://blog.leanote.com/post/casey/Linear-Autoencoder).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://pvirie.wordpress.com/2016/03/29/linear-autoencoders-do-pca/
PCA is restricted to a linear map, while auto encoders can have nonlinear enoder/decoders.

A single layer auto encoder with linear transfer function is nearly equivalent to PCA, where nearly means that the WW found by AE and PCA won't be the same--but the subspace spanned by the respective WW's will.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a detailed mathematical explanation:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.10253

This paper also shows that using a linear autoencoder, it is possible not only to compute the subspace spanned by the PCA vectors, but it is actually possible to compute the principal components themselves.